# get() returned more than one object in Django

Tags: python, django

I know the source of the error, I think. I have an upload view function which sets the following attribute each time a file is uploaded:

```
newdoc.filename = newdoc.docfile.path.split("/")[len(newdoc.docfile.path.split("/"))-1]
```

where newdoc is the file being uploaded. For some reason, this does not seem to take into account the "_1", "_2", etc. that is appended to filenames if the same file has already been uploaded.

I think it sets the filename to the *same* regardless of the "_1" etc. That's why this error occurs, but I do not know why. What is wrong with my filename statement? Here's my get() statement:

```
@login_required
def file(request, filename_regx):
    u_file = request.user.document_set.get(filename=filename_regx)
    return sendfile(request, u_file.docfile.name)
```

This is the template form which passes info to the above view statement:

```
<form action="{% url "file" filename_regx=document.filename %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input class="button2" name="file" value="Download" type="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is the project/urls.py bit:

```
url(r'^file/(?P<filename_regx>.+)$', 'notendur.views.file', name="file"),
```

As I understand it: The user clicks the "Download" button in the form, which sends information to the urls.py file, which then passes its regx to the view function.

Aside from this error, no document is found (server returns 404), even though there is only one file on the server.

Comment: Hi again @Gudmundur. Put `print request.user.document_set.filter(filename=filename_regx)` in your view, and then you can see (in the console running `runserver`) which objects match.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the time you put into me yesterday. I have decided to resolve this problem by circumventing it. I just let the form pass the id of the document instead of its filename.

Comment: I'd like to let you know that this whole debacle has been solved, that is our problem yesterday. This whole time I had been serving sendfile() the USER SIDE path to the file... domain/path/to/file, but it requires the full path to the file on the server's system, of course. So sorry for all this.